# Past Simple vs Present Perfect difference

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

Help me, please, with this extract

> Two elderly couples were enjoying a friendly conversation in the garden when one of the men asked the other, "Fred, how was the memory clinic you went to a month ago?"
>
> "Outstanding," Fred replied. "We **(teach)** visualization, association."

I suppose there we need Passive Voice, but will it be Present Perfect or Past Simple?

We **were taught** or We **have been taught**.

I understand the difference in meaning. I just want to know whether both of the answers work good in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be in the **past simple passive** form (were taught) for two reasons:

**1-** The action has already **ended** as Fred took the course a month ago and is not continuing at the time of that conversation. Also, if you were to use the present perfect, then we would assume Fred is still being taught that course at the time of that speech.

**2-** The first man asked the question in the past tense; thus, the answer **has** to be in the same tense as its question.